# android nfc reading Driver license BAC vs BAP

Tags: android, nfc

Using android device to nfc read my country ID card and **Driver license** (hint: both had 3 lines MRZ of Type **TD1** and the Driver card has a number **8digits+'E'** near the chip, witch I don't know what is used for!?)

- for ID card part I used jmrtd library (BAC protocol, and I successfully read all what I want Data Group {1,2,11,12})
- for Driver License, after reading some standards I supposed to do **BAP** instead-of BAC So I implemented a DLicenseService class the same as PassportService but with some minor changes:

  - changed EF_COM to 001F and AID to A0000002480200 (witch worked in the **first tries**) ...
  - I'm doing BAC as BAP with a custom key derivation algorithm the triplet (docNumber, dateOfBirth, dateOfExpiry) did not work...

My questions are:

- Is there any ***protection against a wrong key derivation*** multiple attempts (assuming BAP == BAC) because the scuba service now is failing!!...please don't tell me there is and my card is blocked...
- Are BAP and BAC equivalent? should I try other protocol?
- Do you know the most used key seed derivation algorithm for Driver License (like SHA1 of last 6 doc digits...)
- Is there a library to deal with Driver License like jmrtd for travel document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, BAC and BAP are equivalent
- The triplet worked for Driver licence
- I implemented all my logic on top of jmrtd code and every think worked fine, basically I implemented :

  - DLicenseService class
  - COMFile and all DGxFile that I'm interested in taking into account the correct SFI and Tags values from the iso/IEC FCD 18013-2 standard.

Comment: Could you share your DLicenceService code?