android nfc reading Driver license
i'm looking for java class like jmrtd as solution to read an nfc driving license based on iso 18013 on android
all what it worked for me until now is the AID = A0000002480200, but i do not know the next steps
can someone, already has solution or know how read it help me

see this answer for a library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62965745/8166854
